# Login with Alamofire post method

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to login like that code:

```
let loginRequest = [
        "UserName" : self.txtUserName.text! as String,
        "Password" : self.txtPassword.text! as String
    ]

    let serverUrl = ServerPath.Path + "/Test/login"

    Alamofire.request(.POST, serverUrl, parameters: loginRequest,encoding: .JSON).responseJSON
        {
            response in switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
            ...
            ...
             case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
```

always getting error

> Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "Invalid value around character 0."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

but I'm trying to static like that operation completed as success

```
let loginRequest = [
        "UserName" : "Test",
        "Password" : "123"
    ]
```

Comment: I believe this is invalid JSON. Can you provide a print of the JSON object you're sending?

Comment: ["Password": "123", "UserName": "test"]

Comment: Your request actually looks good. I believe it is the response from the server that is causing the error. Can you get a dump of the data the server is responding with?

Comment: @MustafaÇakıroğlu try using `responseString` or `responseData` instead of `responseJSON` and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Try setting additional headers for your request with `["Content-Type": "application/json"]` and validate the response with `.validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 300)` and `.validate(contentType: ["application/json"])`

Answer (score 2):

Just change **responseJson** with **resonseString** or **responseData**
your error will gone.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code actually works fine. The error comes from `responseJSON` which means the content being sent back from the server is not proper JSON.